# Creating user with no password in Meteor

Tags: authentication, meteor, accounts

I have a unique user creation flow which is as follows:

1. User comes to my site for the first time and they click a button.
2. I create a User in the DB for them and set a localStorage key with the UID.
3. Use goes about creating data and I save the data in the DB and associate it with the UID.
4. User comes back, and if they have UID set in localStorage, I show them the data they previously created.
5. User can click Register to create a "real" account from which point they will have to login with username and password or another service (e.g. Facebook).

So, how would I accomplish this with Meteor Accounts and the User model?

In a nutshell:

- I need to create User mongo document with no information (about the user).
- I need to authenticate a user by just having a UID (acting as a "password").

Answer (score 8):

1. Register `onCreateUser` to add an "anonymous" field (`{anonymous:1}`)
   when a random password is used, maybe generated with `Meteor.uuid()`.
2. Add a timestamp field
   (`{created:new Date()}`) to clean out old, anonymous accounts.
3. Perform old anonymous user maintenance, like deleting anonymous users more
   than one hour old:
   `Meteor.autorun(function()
   {Meteor.users.find({anonymous:1,$where:"new Date() - this.created >
   360000"}).forEach(function (user) {

   Meteor.users.remove({_id:user._id})}});`
4. On the client:

   1. Always prompt
      for a "nickname." This will become the official username, or will
      sit in the system forever used.
   2. Check if client is logged in. If
      not, create a user with nickname and a "magic number" password,
      which logs you in. When they click register, write "Register" at the
      top, but actually just change their password and `$set:{anonymous:0}`

Don't use localStorage, and don't use UIDs. The session cookie IS your UID.

Comment: Why should I not use localStorage?

Comment: You should use localStorage, just not to store something like a UID. `meteor-accounts` already takes care of the cookie/token/"UID" aspect of what you're trying to achieve.

But, don't let me discourage you from writing your own package that does exactly what you want. Consider checking out the `meteor-accounts` code and think about how to implement an anonymous user. I'd allow users to be created without usernames, and I'd add the anonymous field, with the functionality I described above. It addresses the main limitation of my solution: that you have to start with a nickname.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "magic number" in this context? Are you saying that one should pick a random number to register the anonymous with? Or is this "magic number" programmatically generated?

Comment: Magic number was meant to mean random string. An anonymous user essentially has an account attached to their machine—or perhaps some more complicated fingerprint. They can't recover their account or use it in different places until they convert into a real user, i.e., register.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to help with the authentication, but as for creating a blank User object, I've successfully done the following on the server-side (with a different name...):

`Meteor.users.insert({profile: {name: 'Oompa Loompa'}, foo: 'bar'});`